# Chain method calls with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, method-chaining

I have a class object called Bar which I has as attributes a distinct flavor pd.DataFrame. I want to call the column of each DataFrame through a loop. What I get back, however, is the string itself rather than the call result.

How could I fix this? & what concept am I missing here? Thank you.

```
l=['chocolate', 'vanilla', 'strawberry']

def m(s):
    xd='Bar.'+s+'.columns.str[:5]'
    return xd
 
for s in l:
    print (m(s))
```

which returns:

```
bar.chocolate.columns.str[:5]
bar.vanilla.columns.str[:5]
bar.strawberry.columns.str[:5]
```

Comment: You are creating a string, not sure why you expect this to magically be a call result. You might want to do this in function `m`: `return getattr(Bar, s).columns.str[:5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a string will not access attributes. You need to actually fetch them using `getattr()` like so:

```
l=['chocolate', 'vanilla', 'strawberry']

def m(df, attribute):
    return getattr(df, attribute).columns.str[:5]

for s in l:
    print (m(Bar, s))
```